# Fechar elemento quando clicar em qualquer outra parte da página

Tags: javascript, eventos

Quando o evento é disparado, o elemento abre, mas após isso ele não fecha. Como posso fazer para que, ao clicar fora do "infoValor" o tooltipValor feche?

```
function formTips(){
    var infoValor=document.getElementById("info-input-valor");
    var tooltipValor=document.getElementById("tooltip-input-valor");
    infoValor.onclick=function(){
        if(tooltipValor.style.display!="block"){
            tooltipValor.style.display="block";
        }else{
            tooltipValor.style.display="none";
        }
    }
}formTips();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso poderia ser feito facilmente com o ToolTip do `jQuery`, mas como você está fazendo em `Javascript` puro, terá que capturar o evento click do documento.
Depois verificar se clicou em qualquer elemento fora o seu tooltip, e então esconder o elemento. Você pode fazer isso assim:

```
document.onclick = function(e){
    if(e.target.id != 'info-input-valor'){
        var tooltipValor=document.getElementById("tooltip-input-valor");
        tooltipValor.style.display="none";
    }
};
```

Se quiser pode também alterar o código que você já fez e, na mesma `function`, ver se o id do elemento é o seu tooltip e exibir.